# String set Java 1.4.2

Tags: java, set, java1.4

I had this method for java 1.6. but this doesnt work for java 1.4.2. I came to know that this was introduced from 1.5. So, is there any other equivalent way of writing this in 1.4.2?

```
Set keys = this.getMap().keySet();      

            for (String key :keys){...
                                           ..
                            }
```

Comment: Yes just don't use `foreach` loop use the general for loop.

Comment: Can you show how can I acheive that? I am iterating over each object.

Comment: Hadn't realised this day will come when people learn to use the enhanced for loop first and then come to learn about the old school approach :)

Answer (score 3):

You need an old school iterator:

```
    // Old skool set (no generics)
    Set foo = new HashSet();
    foo.add("bar");
    foo.add("frobnicate");

    // Old skool iterator (no generics, needs typecasting)
    Iterator iFoo = foo.iterator();
    while (iFoo.hasNext())
    {
        String something = (String)iFoo.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

```
Iterator it = this.getMap().keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    // do stuff
    String s = (String)it.next();
}
```

Comment: There are no generics in Java 1.4

Comment: Generics were introduced with Java 1.5!